# Implementing the observer pattern in Smalltalk/VisualWorks

Tags: observer-pattern, smalltalk, visualworks

I'm new to programming with patterns, i spent some hours searching for samples for Smalltalk implementation of the pattern observer but in vain.
If someone can provide me with a concrete sample of the implementation of this pattern under Smalltalk, i will be thankful.

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys for your answers, those were helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The standard implementataion of the observer pattern to be found in Smalltalk would be
the `#changed`/`#update` mechanism.

It goes like this:

```
subject addDependent: anObserver.

subject changed.
```

and then `anObserver` gets send `#update`:

```
MyObservingObject>>update
  "I got called in a #changed chain"
  super update.
  self doUpdatingStuff
```

You can have finer control using `#changed:` and `#update:` (note the colon):

```
subject addDependent: anObserver.
subject changed: subject.
```

and

```
MyObservingObject>>update: anObject
  "I got called in a #changed: chain"
  super update: anObject.
  self doUpdatingStuffWith: anObject
```

However, it is commonly found to use a symbol to indicate what changed:

```
subject addDependent: anObserver.
subject changed: #myNumbers.
```

and

```
MyObservingObject>>update: anObject
  "I got called in a #changed: chain"
  anObject == #myNumbers ifTrue: [
    self doUpdatingStuffForNumbers.
    ^ self "inhibits the super"].
  super update: anObject.
```

When you look at [Squeak](http://www.squeak.org) or [Pharo](http://www.pharo.org), you'll find at least three other
Observer implementations:

- The event handling for Morphic (see `Morph>>#on:send:to:`)
- A similar, more general event handling mechanism, see `Object>>#when:send:to:` and `Object>>#triggerEvent:`
- the *Announcements* framework, encapsulating messages between subject and observer in classes.

You can find a [comparison](https://www.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/hirschfeld/trac/SqueakCommunityProjects/wiki/signals#FeatureComparison) of these at the [Signals project](https://www.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/hirschfeld/trac/SqueakCommunityProjects/wiki/signals), another implementation, but inspired by Qt.

Comment: Is this `changed` message invoked by default? e.g. Can I assume that when something is added/removed from a collection, it's dependents will be updated?

Comment: No, you have to do that yourself. See senders of `#changed` and `#changed:`

Comment: How can I find senders of `#changed` and `#changed`? What is best practice in order to get this behaviour? Change the source of existing classes (like some implementation of `Collection`) or create subclasses to add the behaviour?

Comment: Finding senders in Squeak and Pharo is possible with Alt-n or the MethodFinder / Finder. Collections typically do not send `#changed` themselves. Also you typically do not subclass a collection. A good way is creating you Domain Model class that holds onto the collection (composition) and sends `#changed` when it adds to its collection.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way would be something like this:

in Observer class:

```
observable: anObject
    observable := anObject.

observable
    ^ observable.

notify
    "do something here e.g.:"
    Transcript show: "Some things changed in ", observable asString.
```

And in Observable:

```
initialize
    observers := OrderedCollection new.

addObserver: anObserver
    observers add: anObserver.

removeObserver: anObserver
    observers remove: anObserver.

notifyObservers
    observers do: [ :each | each notify ].
```

But I'd also suggest you to read more about this idea in the chapter about [Announcements Framework](http://pharobooks.gforge.inria.fr/PharoByExampleTwo-Eng/2012-05-17_09:56:30/Announcements.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Also, take a look at [Announcements](http://book.pharo-project.org/book/LanguageAndLibraries/announcements/) Framework.

It is more OO than sending symbols around.

Cheers